# How to check if a list of multiple same element have all the elements of another list marqued with an attribute

Tags: xml, xquery

how to check if a "person" possess all the "vehicules" with within the 'car tag' the attribute status ON ?

```
<deluxe person="John"    brand="Mercedes">
<deluxe person="John"    brand="Lamborgini">
<deluxe person="John"    brand="Seat">
<deluxe person="Tyson"   brand="Volva">
<deluxe person="Miles"   brand="Wolkswagen">
```

this is the list of vehicules :

```
<vehicule>
<car status="on">
<brand>Mercedes</brand>
</car>

<car status="off">
<brand>Peugeot</brand>
</car>

<car status="on">
<brand>Lamborgini</brand>
</car>

<car status="on">
<brand>Seat</brand>
</car>
</vehicules>
```

The result would be that it returns the element `<deluxe person ="John">`

I'm stuck on that since 24 hours.

Comment: What did you try? If you're stuck on that for a day you should at least be able to provide _something_.

Answer (score 0):

I"m sure there are more efficient ways to do this... and not entirely sure what you were asking but I suspect this will help you.

```
let $v :=
<vehicule>
<car status="on">
<brand>Mercedes</brand>
</car>

<car status="off">
<brand>Peugeot</brand>
</car>

<car status="on">
<brand>Lamborgini</brand>
</car>

<car status="on">
<brand>Seat</brand>
</car>
</vehicule> 
let $p := <d>
<deluxe person="John"    brand="Mercedes"/>
<deluxe person="John"    brand="Lamborgini"/>
<deluxe person="John"    brand="Seat"/>
<deluxe person="Tyson"   brand="Volva"/>
<deluxe person="Miles"   brand="Wolkswagen"/>
</d>

let $all := for $i in $v/car[@status="on"]/brand/string() order by $i return $i


for $person in distinct-values($p/deluxe/@person)

  let $brands := for $i in $p/deluxe[@person=$person]/@brand/string() order by $i return $i

  return if ($brands eq $all) then
      $person
  else  
      ()
```

Comment: Note: you can't use `eq` on sequences. Use `count($brands[. = $all]) eq count($all)` instead of `$brands eq $all`. Eric, I am afraid you have been bitten by ML function mapping..

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use [quantified expressions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Quantified_Expressions), you can do the inner loop implicitly; and the query reads rather naturally.

```
let $vehicules :=
  <vehicule><!-- snip --></vehicule> 
let $persons :=
  <d><!-- snip --></d>

for $person in distinct-values($persons//@person)
where
  every $car in $vehicules/car[@status='on']
  satisfies $car/brand=$persons/deluxe[@person=$person]/@brand
return $person
```